# Error use Jquery serialize form with wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Error use use Jquery serialize form  with word-press plugin ?

```
Jquery coding:
jQuery("#btnsave").click(function($){

jQuery("#dv").load("http://localhost:880/wordpress/?page_id=12?myval=myval&"+ $("#frm").serialize());

});
```

PHP coding

```
<form id="frmtest1" name="frmtest1">
                <table style="width:100%;border:1px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2" align="center">Register</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">UserName</td><td align="left"><input type="text"  id="txtusername"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="right">Password</td><td align="left"><input type="text"  id="txtpassword"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td><td align="left"><input type="button" id="btnsave" name="btnsave" value="Save" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
           <tr>
                    <td colspan="2">
                    <?php
                                if(isset($_GET['myval']))
                                {
                                    echo $_GET['txtusername'];
                                    return; 
                                }                   
                    ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr><td colspan="2" align="center" id="dv"></td></tr>
            </table>
             <div id="divmsg"></div>


    </form>
```

Comment: Your HTML markup is cut in half in the middle of a `<td>` tag, is it intentional?

Answer (score 1):

Check out what I changed
http://jsfiddle.net/WjRV5/